# MySQL Error : Invalid default value for 'CREATED_DATE'

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, lamp

I have created an LAMP instance in AWS and while creating DB, I am stuck with this error

```
Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'CREATED_DATE'
```

I checked sql mode and here is the response

```
 mysql>  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| sql_mode      |       |
+---------------+-------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

I am not sure whey this is happening. Here is my db script

```
CREATE TABLE ENTITIES (
  ENTITY_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DATE DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   
  UPDATED_DATE DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,     
  INDEX idx_ENTITIES_id1 (ENTITY_ID ASC)
) 
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=100
;
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm confused about what `UPDATED_DATE DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` does?

Comment: Also, I don't get this error at all.

Comment: I did not get this error in my XAMPP installation but when I tried running in aws instance, this has popped up

Answer (score 4):

Change CREATED_DATE **DATETIME** DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

to

CREATED_DATE **TIMESTAMP** DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: I don't really think that matters, I am able to create this table without a problem.

Comment: Are you using 5.6.5+ version ?

Comment: AWS: Server version: 5.5.42 MySQL Community Server (GPL), This is where error occurred

Comment: It worked in XAMPP installation where I developed and the mysql version there is 5.6.24

Comment: Hm, it must have something to do with AWS then, I suspect. My apologies.

Comment: No, it's not related to AWS.  It's the MySQL Server version. This feature existed *only* for `TIMESTAMP` columns until it was [expanded to include `DATETIME` columns in MySQL 5.6.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html).  Note that `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns [offer different functionality and are not fully interchangeable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html).  Be sure you're using the `TIMESTAMP` column consistent with its design.  Note also, it's generally unwise to develop on a newer version than what's on the production server.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot This is what I was about to say!

Comment: Neat! You get an upvote from me now, I learned something new.

Comment: Could you add this comment to the answer? " It's a problem with the MySQL Server version. DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP existed only for TIMESTAMP columns until it was expanded to include DATETIME columns in MySQL 5.6.5. "

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not because of Amazon EC2 instance.

Amazon EC2 is virtual machine similar to your own local machine.

The error is due to mistake in mysql query you are using, refer the create table mysql query syntax corresponding to the mysql version you have installed in the Amazon EC2 instance.

Hope it will solve the issue.....